# Can I mount volume OR create storage for kafka connector?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka-connect

Can I mount volume OR create storage for AKS kubernetes kafka connector? I need to provide separate volumes for each kafka connector using same kafka connect. I am using yaml files to create kafka connetors.

I started learning kafka recently so not sure if what I tried is correct.
I tried :

1. Creating storage of type PVC for each connector.
2. Creating volumes in kafka connect and mounting them in kafka connectors.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to. Please show what resource files you tried with an [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Rather than mounting a volume, the recommended pattern would be to [build your  own Docker image](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/self-managed/extending.html#add-connectors-or-software) with the connectors